# Automatically create folder in sent messages with same folder structure as inbox

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I'm wondering if it's possible to have Outlook automatically create a folder with the same path as I have sent my e-mail from?

Let's say I have an e-mail in the following folderstructure: 
Inbox-->Project-->Project Location-->Project Name

When I click reply I would like it to create the same path under Sent items.

Sent-->Project-->Project Location-->Project Name
If the path already exists it should just move the mail there.

Is this at all possible, see image for details:

[image: Outlook Inbox/Sent folderstructure]

Using Outlook with Office Pro Plus 365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook has no builtin feature that does what you are asking for. The closest option is to Save a copy of the sent item in the same folder with the original message being replied to.

It's possible what you're after could be accomplished with VBA code, but writing such a script would be outside the scope of an answer on Super User.

Comment: Appreciate the help, this could work just fine. Is there anyway to do this to existing mails sent? So they get moved to whatever folder they were answered from?

Comment: Nope. You'd have to go back manually and move them to the correct folder. Quite a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also view email messages by conversation as a workaround:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-email-messages-by-conversation-0eeec76c-f59b-4834-98e6-05cfdfa9fb07

So you can find the reply history in the conversation view.(same folder path)